# check if a value exists in array

Tags: php, arrays, array-key-exists

I am trying this code to check if a value exists in an array.

```
$arr = array ('2' => '0', '3' => '0.58');

$num=3;
if (array_key_exists($num, $arr)) {
    echo (array_key_exists($num, $arr)); //show the index, in this case 1
}
```

What i want is show the correspondent value, in other words, `0.58`

How can i do that ?

Comment: You mean `$arr['3']`? Where are you getting `$numCol` and `$IA` from?

Comment: The index of the key `3` is not `1`, it's `3`. It's the *second* entry in the array, but this information is not necessarily retrievable.

Comment: sorry, I changed the names of the variables when I copied, and i forgot these ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
$arr = array ('2' => '0', '3' => '0.58');

$num=3;
if (array_key_exists($num, $arr)) {
    echo $arr[$num];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the key or index position of the value you want, there are two functions that you could use, [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) or [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

`array_key_exists()` checks an array to see if the key you specified exists within the array. It does not check to see if there is a value associated with this key. In other words the key may be set in the array, however the value could be null.

An example usage:

```
$arr = array ('2' => '0', '3' => '0.58');

$num=3;
if (array_key_exists($num, $arr)) {
  echo $arr[$num];
}
```

`isset()` can be used to see if a value is set in a specific array index.

An example usage:

```
$arr = array ('2' => '0', '3' => '0.58');

$num=3;
if (isset($arr[$num])) {
  echo $arr[$num];
}
```

**Since you seem to be asking to only check to see if a specific value exists within an array**, you can take a look at using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) which will scan the values of the array and return true or false depending on if it found the value.

An example usage:

```
$arr = array ('2' => '0', '3' => '0.58');
$needle = '0.58';
if (in_array($needle, $arr)) {
  echo "found: $needle";
}
```

Additionally, php.net has a lot of other [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that you should familiarize yourself with.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(in_array(0.58, $arr)); // 3
```

relevant [docs](http://php.net/in_array).

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    '2' => '0',
    '3' => '0.58'
    );

$num = 3;
if (array_key_exists($num, $arr)) {
    echo $arr[$num];
    //  0.58
}
echo '<br/>';
$val = '0.58';
if (in_array($val, $arr)) {
    echo '0.58 found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that unless you expect NULL values `isset($arr[$num])` is equivalent but lot faster to `array_key_exists`.